# Setting com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false in code is not working

Tags: java, ssl, aws-lambda

I am working on a java application which we are deploying on AWS Lambda.

In our test / dev environment we are using self signed certificates and using Lambda when we make an XML RPC call to our server which is using our self signed certificates and it fails.

I would like to disable SSL certificate verification for our test / dev environment and for this I am setting up the following properties as false in code:

```
        System.setProperty("com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation", "false");
        System.setProperty("ocsp.enable", "false");
```

Still when code is executed and XML RPC call is made it fails. Is there something I am missing which is causing this failure? Or I would need to implement complete flow for local keystore to add my certificate there for testing this as part of my code?

Comment: Which JDK are you exactly using? Oracle 1.8?

Comment: It is java-1.8.0-openjdk (running on Amazon Linux)

Comment: So you did test that the settings above work at all using openjdk not a oracle jdk? I'm not sure if it's supported at all: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/JDK8/Java+Dependency+Analysis+Tool

Comment: maybe setting `com.ibm.jsse2.checkRevocation=false` helps, idk